# How can I update total values for a Contact with transaction value from another model

Tags: c#, foreach, model

I have two sql tables with these two models

I would love to update for my dashboard the sum of supplier points of the same contacts of the timereport of the same contact. If the contact does not exist on dashboard I would love to create a new record.

See my two classes attached dashboard and time sheet as well as the the index page get with the sample.
However I need help how to write it since I'm new to this.

```
// ===========================
// My class with total values
// ===========================
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WorkCollaboration.Models
{
    public class ContactDashboard
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Contact Id"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact Id Required")]
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Customer Need Demands")]
        public decimal NumberofCusNeedDemands { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Supplier Offerings")]
        public decimal NumberofTalentOfferings { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Customer Platin Badges")]
        public int NumberofCusBadgesPlatin{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Customer Gold Badges")]
        public int NumberofCusBadgesGold{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Customer Silver Badges")]
        public int NumberofCusBadgesSilver{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Customer Bronze Badges")]
        public int NumberofCusBadgesBronze{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Customer Iron Badges")]
        public int NumberofCusBadgesIron{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Supplier Platin Badges")]
        public int NumberofSupBadgesPlatin{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Supplier Gold Badges")]
        public int NumberofSupBadgesGold{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Supplier Silver Badges")]
        public int NumberofSupBadgesSilver{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Supplier Bronze Badges")]
        public int NumberofSupBadgesBronze{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number of Supplier Iron Badges")]
        public int NumberofSupBadgesIron{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Total Customer Points")]
        public decimal NumberofTotalCusPoints{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Total Supplier Points")]
        public decimal NumberofTotalSupPoints{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Average Customer Recession")]
        public int AverageofCusRecessions{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Average Supplier Recession")]
        public int AverageofSupRecessions{ get; set; }
    }
}

//========================================
//My class with transaction values
//========================================

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WorkCollaboration.Models
{
    public class TimeReport
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Time Report Id"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Time Report Id Required")] 
        public int TimeReportId { get; set; }
        public int TimeReportCustomerNeedContactId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Supplier Contact Id"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Supplier Contact Id 
        Required")]
        public int TimeReportSupplierTalentContactId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Time Report Date"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Time Report Date Required")]
        public DateTime TimeReportDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Time Report Hours"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Time Report Hours Required")]
        public decimal TimeReportHours { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Time Report Text"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Time Report Text Required")]
        public string TimeReportText { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Time Report State"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Time Report State Required")]
        public string TimeReportState { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Supplier Points Value")]
        public decimal TimeReportSupContactPointValue { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I'm in my index page and want to update always on get the sum of point values

```
    [BindProperty]
    public TimeReport TimeReport { get; set; }
    public CustomerNeed CustomerNeed { get; set; }
    public SupplierTalent SupplierTalent { get; set; }
    public IList<Models.ContactDashboard> ContactDashboard { get;set; }
    
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
            ContactDashboard = await _context.ContactDashboard.ToListAsync();

    // something like this 
    foreach field in TimeReport

    if (TimeReport.TimeReportSupplierTalentContactId = ContactDashboard.ContactId)
    {
        Update ContactDashboard Record
        ContactDashboard.NumberofTotalSupPoints = ContactDashboard.NumberofTotalSupPoints + 
        TimeReport.TimeReportSupContactPointValue
    }
    else 
    {
        Insert new Contact in ContactDashboard

        ContactDashboard.ContactId = TimeReport.TimeReportSupplierTalentContactId
        ContactDashboard.NumberofTotalSupPoints = ContactDashboard.NumberofTotalSupPoints + 
        TimeReport.TimeReportSupContactPointValue
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Update 2.3.2021

I made progress on the problem see my comment.

Iteration to my model works as well. Creating a record if missing works and update as well.

See my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NToastNotify;
using WorkCollaboration.Data;
using WorkCollaboration.Models;

namespace WorkCollaboration.Pages.ContactDashboardOverview
{
    public class DashboardModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly WorkCollaboration.Data.WorkCollaborationContext _context;
        private readonly IToastNotification toastNotification;
        public DashboardModel(WorkCollaboration.Data.WorkCollaborationContext context, IToastNotification toastNotification)
        {
            _context = context;
            this.toastNotification = toastNotification;
        }



        [BindProperty]
        public IList<Models.ContactDashboardOverview> ContactDashboardOverview { get;set; }
        public IList<Models.Contact> Contact { get;set; }
        public IList<Models.TimeReport> TimeReport { get;set; }
        public Models.ContactDashboard ContactDashboard { get; set; }

        bool success_state;

        private bool CreatedNewDashboardContact(int Contactid)
        {
            ////============================================
            //// Adding new Dashboard Contact
            ////============================================
            var ContactDashboardAdd = new Models.ContactDashboard();
            ContactDashboardAdd.ContactId = Contactid;
            _context.ContactDashboard.Add(ContactDashboardAdd);
            _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            success_state = true;
            return success_state;
        }

        private bool UpdateExistingDashboardContact(int Contactid, decimal SupplierPoints)
        {
            ////============================================
            //// Updateing Dashboard Contact
            ////============================================
            var ContactDashboardUpdate = new Models.ContactDashboard();
            ContactDashboardUpdate.ContactId = Contactid;
            ContactDashboardUpdate.NumberofTotalSupPoints = SupplierPoints;


            _context.Attach(ContactDashboardUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ContactDashboardExists(ContactDashboardUpdate.ContactId))
                {
                    success_state = false;
                    return success_state;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            success_state = true;
            return success_state;
        }

        private bool ContactDashboardExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.ContactDashboard.Any(e => e.ContactId == id);
        }



        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            string SessionKeyName = "_Name";
            string SessionKeyId = "_Id";
            string SessionKeyDate = "_Date";
            string SessionKeyLang = "_Lang";

            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string valueSystemKeyDates = now.ToString("yyyymmddhh:mm:ss");

            var SessionIdDate = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyDate);
            var SessionIdId = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyId);
            var SessionIdName = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
            var SessionIdLang = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyLang);

            if (SessionIdId == "" | SessionIdId == null)
            {
                // Info
                toastNotification.AddInfoToastMessage("Sie sind nicht eingelogged");
                toastNotification.AddInfoToastMessage("You are not logged in");
                toastNotification.AddInfoToastMessage("Vous n'êtes pas connecté");
                RedirectToPage("/LogonService/LoginCreate");
            }
            
            //=========================================
            // Change Culture on specific user language
            //=========================================
            if (SessionIdLang == "DE")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-CH");
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                new CultureInfo("de-CH");
            }

            //=========================================
            // Change Culture on specific user language
            //=========================================
            if (SessionIdLang == "EN")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                new CultureInfo("en-US");
            }

            //=========================================
            // Change Culture on specific user language
            //=========================================
            if (SessionIdLang == "FR")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            }


            ContactDashboardOverview = await _context.ContactDashboardOverview.ToListAsync();
            Contact = await _context.Contact.ToListAsync();
            TimeReport = await _context.TimeReport.ToListAsync();


            foreach (var contactitem in Contact)
            {
                
                if (!ContactDashboardExists(contactitem.ContactId))
                {
                    // Create new
                    CreatedNewDashboardContact(contactitem.ContactId);
                }
            }



            foreach (var contactitem in Contact)
            {
                foreach (var timereportitem in TimeReport)
                {
                    if (contactitem.ContactId == timereportitem.TimeReportSupplierTalentContactId)
                    {
                        foreach (var dashboarditem in ContactDashboardOverview)
                        {
                            if (contactitem.ContactId == dashboarditem.ContactId)
                            {
                            
                                // Update because it is found
                                dashboarditem.NumberofTotalSupPoints = dashboarditem.NumberofTotalSupPoints +
                                                                       timereportitem.TimeReportSupContactPointValue;
                                UpdateExistingDashboardContact(dashboarditem.ContactId,
                                    dashboarditem.NumberofTotalSupPoints);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }





            //Success
            if (SessionIdLang == "DE")
            {
                toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Daten erfolgreich geladen");
            }
            if (SessionIdLang == "EN")
            {
                toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Data loaded successfully");
            }
            if (SessionIdLang == "FR")
            {
                toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Chargement des données réussi");
            }



        }
    }
}
```

However I get this error when looping trough. In debugger I get it not always but sometimes. This on create and on update

[image: SQL Error]

Tks on helping

Comment: I made some Progress on my issue. I found the way to iterate over my model and get the information. However in dubugger I get from time to time this sql error. What is the reason for it? Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two loops contacts in contact. Inside the loop I was updating my dashboard. Then I had a second loop updating next aggregation values...

When ever in the 2nd loop I was trying to update my dashboard I got the error about the instance of entity is already attached or can not be tracked.

No tracking option did not help, switching from asynchronous to synchronous did not help. Putting in from of each loop new Model did not help...

The solution was to put everything in one loop an now it works nice as I wanted to have it. Unfortunately keep code simple is not anymore really true.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NToastNotify;
using WorkCollaboration.Data;
using WorkCollaboration.Models;

namespace WorkCollaboration.Pages.ContactDashboard
{
    public class CalcModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly WorkCollaboration.Data.WorkCollaborationContext _context;
        private readonly IToastNotification toastNotification;

        public CalcModel(WorkCollaboration.Data.WorkCollaborationContext context, IToastNotification toastNotification)
        {
            _context = context;
            this.toastNotification = toastNotification;
        }

        [BindProperty] 
        public Models.ContactDashboard ContactDashboard { get; set; }
        public IList<Models.ContactDashboard> ContactDashboardList { get; set; }        
        public IList<Models.Contact> Contact { get; set; }
        public IList<Models.CustomerNeed> CustomerNeed {get; set; }
        public IList<Models.SupplierTalent> SupplierTalent { get; set; }
        public IList<Models.BadgesforCusContact> BadgesforCusContact { get; set; }
        public IList<Models.BadgesforSupContact> BadgesforSupContact { get; set; }
        public IList<Models.PointsforCusContact> PointsforCusContact { get; set; }
        public IList<Models.PointsforSupContact> PointsforSupContact { get; set; }
        public IList<Models.RatingfromSupContactToCusContact> RatingfromSupContactToCusContact { get; set; }
        public IList<Models.RatingfromCusContactToSupContact> RatingfromCusContactToSupContact { get; set; }
        public IList<Models.TimeReport> TimeReport { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            string SessionKeyName = "_Name";
            string SessionKeyId = "_Id";
            string SessionKeyDate = "_Date";
            string SessionKeyLang = "_Lang";

            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string valueSystemKeyDates = now.ToString("yyyymmddhh:mm:ss");

            var SessionIdDate = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyDate);
            var SessionIdId = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyId);
            var SessionIdName = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
            var SessionIdLang = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyLang);

            if (SessionIdId == "" | SessionIdId == null)
            {
                // Info
                toastNotification.AddInfoToastMessage("Sie sind nicht eingelogged");
                toastNotification.AddInfoToastMessage("You are not logged in");
                toastNotification.AddInfoToastMessage("Vous n'êtes pas connecté");
                return RedirectToPage("/LogonService/LoginCreate");
            }

            //=========================================
            // Change Culture on specific user language
            //=========================================
            if (SessionIdLang == "DE")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-CH");
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                new CultureInfo("de-CH");
            }

            //=========================================
            // Change Culture on specific user language
            //=========================================
            if (SessionIdLang == "EN")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                new CultureInfo("en-US");
            }

            //=========================================
            // Change Culture on specific user language
            //=========================================
            if (SessionIdLang == "FR")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            }

            //Success
            if (SessionIdLang == "DE")
            {
                toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Daten erfolgreich geladen");
            }

            if (SessionIdLang == "EN")
            {
                toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Data loaded successfully");
            }

            if (SessionIdLang == "FR")
            {
                toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Chargement des données réussi");
            }

            return Page();
        }


        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {

            _context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

            string SessionKeyName = "_Name";
            string SessionKeyId = "_Id";
            string SessionKeyDate = "_Date";
            string SessionKeyLang = "_Lang";

            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string valueSystemKeyDates = now.ToString("yyyymmddhh:mm:ss");

            var SessionIdDate = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyDate);
            var SessionIdId = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyId);
            var SessionIdName = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
            var SessionIdLang = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyLang);

            if (SessionIdId == "" | SessionIdId == null)
            {
                // Info
                toastNotification.AddInfoToastMessage("Sie sind nicht eingelogged");
                toastNotification.AddInfoToastMessage("You are not logged in");
                toastNotification.AddInfoToastMessage("Vous n'êtes pas connecté");
                RedirectToPage("/LogonService/LoginCreate");
            }

            //=========================================
            // Change Culture on specific user language
            //=========================================
            if (SessionIdLang == "DE")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-CH");
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                new CultureInfo("de-CH");
            }

            //=========================================
            // Change Culture on specific user language
            //=========================================
            if (SessionIdLang == "EN")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                new CultureInfo("en-US");
            }

            //=========================================
            // Change Culture on specific user language
            //=========================================
            if (SessionIdLang == "FR")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            }

            Contact = await _context.Contact.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            ContactDashboardList = await _context.ContactDashboard.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            CustomerNeed = await _context.CustomerNeed.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            SupplierTalent = await _context.SupplierTalent.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            BadgesforCusContact = await _context.BadgesforCusContact.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            BadgesforSupContact = await _context.BadgesforSupContact.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            PointsforCusContact = await _context.PointsforCusContact.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            PointsforSupContact = await _context.PointsforSupContact.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            RatingfromSupContactToCusContact = await _context.RatingfromSupContactToCusContact.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            RatingfromCusContactToSupContact = await _context.RatingfromCusContactToSupContact.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            TimeReport = await _context.TimeReport.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

            //=================================================================
            // Adding new Dashboard Contact except 0 Contact Id (not logged In)
            //=================================================================
            _context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
            var ContactDashboard = new Models.ContactDashboard();
            
            // Make Loop over all contacts
            foreach (var contactitem in Contact)
            {
                // Create new dashboard contact if new contacts are created



                if (contactitem.ContactId != 0)
                { 

                    if (!ContactDashboardExists(contactitem.ContactId))
                    {
                        ContactDashboard.DashboardContactId = contactitem.ContactId;
                        _context.ContactDashboard.Add(ContactDashboard);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                }
            }


            //=================================================================
            // Clear all values except 0 Contact Id (not logged In)
            //=================================================================

            // Make Loop over all contacts
            foreach (var contactitem in Contact)
            {
                if (contactitem.ContactId !=0)
                { 
                    ContactDashboard = await _context.ContactDashboard.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DashboardContactId == contactitem.ContactId);
                    ContactDashboard.DashboardContactId = contactitem.ContactId;

                    // Reset all values to zero (Basis for add-up calculation)
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofCusNeedDemands = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofTalentOfferings = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesPlatin = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesGold = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesSilver = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesBronze = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesIron = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesPlatin = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesGold = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesSilver = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesBronze = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesIron = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofTotalCusPoints = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofTotalSupPoints = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofCusRecessions = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofSupRecessions = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.ValueofCusRecessions = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.ValueofSupRecessions = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofCusHours = 0;
                    ContactDashboard.NumberofSupHours = 0;

                   // Make Loop over all Customer Needs records
                   var customerneeditems = CustomerNeed.Where(x => x.NeedContactId == contactitem.ContactId);

                    foreach (var customerneeditem in customerneeditems)
                    {
                        ContactDashboard.NumberofCusNeedDemands = ContactDashboard.NumberofCusNeedDemands + 1;
                        ContactDashboard.NumberofCusHours = ContactDashboard.NumberofCusHours + customerneeditem.NeedTimeExpectedHours;
                    }

                    // Make Loop over all supplier talents offers records
                    var suppliertanlenttitems = SupplierTalent.Where(x => x.TalentContactId == contactitem.ContactId);

                    foreach (var suppliertanlenttitem in suppliertanlenttitems)
                    {
                        ContactDashboard.NumberofTalentOfferings = ContactDashboard.NumberofTalentOfferings + 1;
                    }

                    // Make Loop over all Customer badges records
                    var badgesforcusitems = BadgesforCusContact.Where(x => x.BadgesCusContactId == contactitem.ContactId);

                    foreach (var badgesforcusitem in badgesforcusitems)
                    {
                        if (badgesforcusitem.BadgesLevel == "Platin")
                        {
                            ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesPlatin = ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesPlatin + 1;
                        }
                        if (badgesforcusitem.BadgesLevel == "Gold")
                        {
                            ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesGold = ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesGold + 1;
                        }
                        if (badgesforcusitem.BadgesLevel == "Silver")
                        {
                            ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesSilver = ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesSilver + 1;
                        }
                        if (badgesforcusitem.BadgesLevel == "Bronze")
                        {
                            ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesBronze = ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesBronze + 1;
                        }
                        if (badgesforcusitem.BadgesLevel == "Iron")
                        {
                            ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesIron = ContactDashboard.NumberofCusBadgesIron + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    // Make Loop over all Supplier badges records
                    var badgesforsupitems = BadgesforSupContact.Where(x => x.BadgesSupContactId == contactitem.ContactId);

                    foreach (var badgesforsupitem in badgesforsupitems)
                    {
                        if (badgesforsupitem.BadgesLevel == "Platin")
                        {
                            ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesPlatin = ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesPlatin + 1;
                        }
                        if (badgesforsupitem.BadgesLevel == "Gold")
                        {
                            ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesGold = ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesGold + 1;
                        }
                        if (badgesforsupitem.BadgesLevel == "Silver")
                        {
                            ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesSilver = ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesSilver + 1;
                        }
                        if (badgesforsupitem.BadgesLevel == "Bronze")
                        {
                            ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesBronze = ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesBronze + 1;
                        }
                        if (badgesforsupitem.BadgesLevel == "Iron")
                        {
                            ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesIron = ContactDashboard.NumberofSupBadgesIron + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    // Make Loop over all Customer Points records
                    var cuspointsitems = PointsforCusContact.Where(x => x.PointsCusContactId == contactitem.ContactId);

                    foreach (var cuspointsitem in cuspointsitems)
                    {
                        ContactDashboard.NumberofTotalCusPoints = ContactDashboard.NumberofTotalCusPoints + cuspointsitem.PointsTotal;
                    }

                    // Make Loop over all Supplier Points records
                    var suppointsitems = PointsforSupContact.Where(x => x.PointsSupContactId == contactitem.ContactId);

                    foreach (var suppointsitem in suppointsitems)
                    {
                        ContactDashboard.NumberofTotalSupPoints = ContactDashboard.NumberofTotalSupPoints + suppointsitem.PointsTotal;
                    }

                    // Make Loop over all Customer Recessions records
                    var cusrecessionstitems = RatingfromSupContactToCusContact.Where(x => x.RatingCusContactId == contactitem.ContactId);

                    foreach (var cusrecessionstitem in cusrecessionstitems)
                    {
                        ContactDashboard.NumberofCusRecessions = ContactDashboard.NumberofCusRecessions + 1;

                        ContactDashboard.ValueofCusRecessions = ContactDashboard.ValueofCusRecessions +
                                                                cusrecessionstitem.RatingValue;

                    }

                    // Make Loop over all Supplier Recessions records
                    var suprecessionstitems = RatingfromCusContactToSupContact.Where(x => x.RatingSupContactId == contactitem.ContactId);

                    foreach (var suprecessionstitem in suprecessionstitems)
                    {
                        ContactDashboard.NumberofSupRecessions = ContactDashboard.NumberofSupRecessions + 1;
                        ContactDashboard.ValueofSupRecessions = ContactDashboard.ValueofSupRecessions +
                                                                suprecessionstitem.RatingValue;

                    }

                    // Make Loop over all Timesheet records
                    var timesheettitems = TimeReport.Where(x => x.TimeReportSupplierTalentContactId == contactitem.ContactId);

                    foreach (var timesheettitem in timesheettitems)
                    {
                        ContactDashboard.NumberofSupHours = ContactDashboard.NumberofSupHours +
                                                            timesheettitem.TimeReportHours;

                    }

                    _context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
                    _context.Attach(ContactDashboard).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }

            //Success
            if (SessionIdLang == "DE")
            {
                toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Daten erfolgreich berechnet");
            }

            if (SessionIdLang == "EN")
            {
                toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Data add up successfully");
            }

            if (SessionIdLang == "FR")
            {
                toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Chargement des données réussi");
            }

            return RedirectToPage("/ContactDashboardOverview/Index");
        }

        private bool ContactDashboardExists(int id)
        {
            _context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
            return _context.ContactDashboard.Any(e => e.DashboardContactId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps for others who fight with this error.